# Depth first search implementation: algorithm keeps on searching out only to the right

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

I have a Depth First Search exercise.

The goal of this exercise is to find a valid path from the beginning of the maze to the end.

This is my code:

#### Node.java

```java
public class Node
{
    private int position;
    private int type;
    private boolean IsExit;
 
    public Node(int position,int type,boolean IsExit)
    {
        this.position = position;
        this.type = type;
        this.IsExit = IsExit;
    }

    public int getPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }
    
    public int getType()
    {
        return type;
    }
    
    public boolean getIsExit()
    {
        return IsExit;
    }

    public void setIsExit(boolean b)
    {
        IsExit = b;
    }
}
```

#### SearchAlgorithm.java

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.System;

public class SearchAlgorithm
{
    protected int gridSize;
    protected int gridLength;
    protected Node[][] grid;
    
    public SearchAlgorithm(int gridSize)
    {
        int gridLength  = (int) Math.sqrt(gridSize);
        this.gridSize = gridSize;
        this.gridLength = gridLength;
        Node[][]arr = new Node[gridLength][gridLength];
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<gridSize;i++)
        {
            Node n;
            if(i==0)
            {
                n= new Node(i,0,false);
                arr[i][i] = n;
            }
            else if(i==gridSize-1)
            {
                n = new Node(i,0,true);
                arr[gridLength-1][gridLength-1] = n;
            }
            else
            {
                int x = i%gridLength;
                int y = i/gridLength;
                n = new Node(i,r.nextInt(2),false);
                arr[x][y] = n;
            }
        }
        this.grid = arr;
    }
        
    public void print()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<gridLength;i++)
        {
           for(int j=0;j<gridLength;j++)
           {
                System.out.print("Position:"+grid[j][i].getPosition()+" Type:"+grid[j][i].getType()+" ");
           }
           System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The `grid` is a 2 dimensional array of the class `Node`: It has 2 coordinates x and y. X is found by `Node.position%i` and Y is found by `Node.position/i`.

#### DeepFirstSearch.java

```java
import java.lang.System;

public class DeepFirstSearch extends SearchAlgorithm {
    private  int[] position;

    public DeepFirstSearch(int gridSize) {
        super(gridSize);
        position = new int[2];
        position[0]=0;
        position[1]=0;
    }
    
    public int calc(int[]position)
    {
        System.out.println(grid[position[0]][position[1]].getPosition());
        if(grid[position[0]][position[1]].getType()==1)
        {
           System.out.println("Path been blocked!Exit status:"+1);
           return 1;
        }
        else if(grid[position[0]][position[1]].getIsExit())
        {
            System.out.println("Path been found");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(position[0]<gridLength-1)
            {
               position[0]++;
               calc(position);
            }
            if(position[0]>0)
            {
                position[0]--;
                calc(position);
            }
            if(position[1]<gridLength-1)
            {
                position[1]++;
                calc(position);
            }
            if(position[1]>0)
            {
                position[1]--;
                calc(position);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The `int[] position` stores the position of the current `Node`. If we hit a `Node` with `Node.getType()==1` then the path is not valid. A `Node` with `getIsExit()==true` is the desired destination (it is only 1 in my example).

#### Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeepFirstSearch sch = new DeepFirstSearch(9);
        sch.print();
        int[]pos = {0,0};
        sch.calc(pos);
    }
}
```

I set up the initial position to `{0,0}` in the `main` function.

The issue is that when I run the program I get this output:

```
Position:0 Type:0 Position:1 Type:0 Position:2 Type:1 
Position:3 Type:1 Position:4 Type:1 Position:5 Type:1 
Position:6 Type:0 Position:7 Type:1 Position:8 Type:0 
0
1
2
Path been blocked!Exit status:1
1
2
Path been blocked!Exit status:1
1
2
Path been blocked!Exit status:1
1
2
Path been blocked!Exit status:1
1
2
...
```

and so it continues on until a `StackOverflowException` is thrown. Why does the algorithm keep on visiting the same nodes?

Comment: The output you provided is not generated by the code you have provided. Notably the first three lines of output... Please provide the code that initialises the grid and calls your function.

Comment: Ok cool will do!.

Comment: @trincot do you know how to link in files?

Comment: You shouldn't link to files. The relevent code should be embedded inside the question, but only enough code to reproduce the problem. Not more, not less.

Comment: Well I want to upload the .java files somehow?

Comment: No need to upload files, just copy the text as a [mcve]. Please format the code. If there's too much of it to share, then please minimize it further so it's in scope and answerable, without anything extra.

Comment: There you go I tried to keep down the code simple so I wouldnt have to make you read all 3 .java files but I guess they are required for the problem to be understood!

Comment: Please improve the quality of the code. Indention , remove empty lines (, maybe some comments what your intentions are in non trivial parts of the code ) ...

Comment: Please clean up your question. You have now provided some pieces of code twice.

Comment: Please explain what the expected output is.

Comment: @trincot you want me to remove off the code blocks before the edit?

Comment: I think it is clear what I wrote? Avoid duplicate code in the question. So yes, remove the code blocks that you repeat later.

Comment: Well I expected :"0 1 2 ->Path has been blocked! 1 4 ->Path has been blocked" but it instead is looping in "1 2".It takes out of account the 1 4 possible path.

Comment: It is looping because you haven't coded that a cell shouldn't be visited twice.

Comment: But why is it looping?I dont understand.If the path leads to a dead end , we enter in our base case of recursion.

Comment: Yes, and then the caller of that recursive call will call `calc` on a position that it came from -> cycle.

Comment: But isnt it that the point?To check over all possible paths starting from 1 node?When the recursive function returns a number it will move to the next instruction which is to move to the bottom.

Comment: It is OK to come back to the same node (when unwinding recursion), but it is wrong to make a recursive call to a node you have already visited. That produces a cycle in your search path, and you keep running in circles, going ever deeper into recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not implemented the notion of "visited". Positions that you have visited, should not be visited again. This is a basic principle in search algorithms. A node is called "visited" when you are ready to look at its neighbors. As you make a recursive call for a neighbor, that neighbor gets visited. If that neighbor is found to already have been visited, that indicates that neighbor is on the path you have already traversed, and so it should not be visited again. If you would, you would run in cycles, which is the problem you have encountered.

So you need to maintain a visited status somewhere. There are many ways to do that. One is to add a boolean field to `Node`.

```
public class Node
{
    private int position;
    private int type;
    private boolean IsExit;
    private boolean isVisited; // See also getter & setter

    public Node(int position,int type,boolean IsExit)
    {
        this.position = position;
        this.type = type;
        this.IsExit = IsExit;
        this.isVisited = false;
    }

    public int getPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }
    
    public int getType()
    {
        return type;
    }
    
    public boolean getIsExit()
    {
        return IsExit;
    }

    public void setIsExit(boolean b)
    {
        IsExit = b;
    }

    public boolean getIsVisited() {
        return isVisited;
    }
    
    public void setIsVisited(boolean b) {
        isVisited = b;
    }
}
```

I would also suggest to have `calc` return a `boolean` instead of `int`, since that is really what you do there: either the search succeeds, or it doesn't.

Another problem is that the change you make to `position` just before making the recursive call, should be reverted once you are back. Otherwise the calculation for the next neighbor position will be wrong.

So for example this:

```
    {
        position[0]++;
        calc(position);
    }
```

should become:

```
    {
        position[0]++;
        calc(position);
        position[0]--; // Bring position back to the original
    }
```

This is quite cumbersome. Moreover, `position` should not be a field; it is just a local piece of information that is passed along with each recursive call.

It will also be easier if you don't pass `position` as an array of two, but pass two separate `int`s, one for `row`, one for `col`.

Here is the updated `calc` method:

```
import java.lang.System;

class DeepFirstSearch extends SearchAlgorithm {
    public DeepFirstSearch(int gridSize) {
        super(gridSize);
    }
        
    public boolean calc(int row, int col)
    {
        // Perform all validity checks here, and test node was not yet visited
        if (   row >= gridLength
            || row < 0
            || col >= gridLength
            || col < 0
            || grid[row][col].getIsVisited()
        ) {
            return false; // Target was not found here
        }
        Node node = grid[row][col];
        node.setIsVisited(true); // Mark as visited
        System.out.println(node.getPosition());
        if (node.getType() == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Path been blocked!Exit status: false");
            return false; // Target was not found here
        }
        else if(node.getIsExit())
        {
            System.out.println("Path been found");
            return true; // Target found!
        }
        else
        {
            // Use short circuit evaluation: as soon as one of the calls 
            //   returns true, no further calls will be made, and the return
            //   value will be true if and only when that happens.
            return calc(row + 1, col) || calc(row - 1, col) 
                || calc(row, col + 1) || calc(row, col - 1); 
        }
    }
}
```

The initial call should then be:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeepFirstSearch sch = new DeepFirstSearch(9);
        sch.print();
        sch.calc(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I actually prefer the array for the position to 2 seperate variables because it is more organized for but thanks a lot regardless!Have a good day!

Comment: You can still keep that position, but you will have less elegant code for the recursive calls then. One problem then is that you need to undo a change to a position before making the next recursive call, which is also a problem in your code. To me this suggests that `position` is a bad idea.