# Breadth first search algorithm is wrong

Tags: java, data-structures, breadth-first-search

[Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77541166/depth-first-search-implementation-algorithm-keeps-on-searching-out-only-to-the) I asked a question on the DFS. Today I am trying to implement the BFS.

The .java classes not given out in this thread are taken from the previous question.

I have written this class:

`BreadthFirstSearch.java`

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.lang.System;

public class BreadthFirstSearch extends SearchAlgorithm{

    public BreadthFirstSearch(int gridSize)
    {
        super(gridSize);
    }

    public void calc(int[]pos)
    {
        ArrayDeque<int[]>arrayDeque = new ArrayDeque<>();
        arrayDeque.add(pos);
        while(!arrayDeque.isEmpty())
        {
            for(int[]i:arrayDeque) {
                System.out.println(grid[i[0]][i[1]].getPosition());
                if (grid[i[0]][i[1]].getIsExit()) {
                    System.out.println("Path been found!");
                    arrayDeque.remove(i);
                } else if (grid[i[0]][i[1]].getType() == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Path been blocked!");
                    arrayDeque.remove(i);
                } else if (grid[i[0]][i[1]].getIsVisited()) {
                    arrayDeque.remove(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    grid[i[0]][i[1]].setIsVisited(true);
                    if (i[0] < gridLength - 1) {
                        int[] c = i;
                        c[0]++;
                        arrayDeque.add(c);
                    }
                    if (i[0] > 0) {
                        int[] d = i;
                        d[0]--;
                        arrayDeque.add(d);
                    }
                    if (i[1] < gridLength - 1) {
                        int[] e = i;
                        e[1]++;
                        arrayDeque.add(e);
                    }
                    if (i[1] > 0) {
                        int[] f = i;
                        f[1]--;
                        arrayDeque.add(f);
                    }
                    arrayDeque.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I have added in the Main.java class this:

```
BreadthFirstSearch bfs = new BreadthFirstSearch(9);
bfs.print();
bfs.calc(pos);
```

For the constructor of `BreadthFirstSearch.java` I get this matrix:

```
Position:0 Type:0 Position:1 Type:0 Position:2 Type:1 
Position:3 Type:0 Position:4 Type:1 Position:5 Type:1 
Position:6 Type:1 Position:7 Type:0 Position:8 Type:0
```

```
while(!arrayDeque.isEmpty())
{
    for(int[]i:arrayDeque) {
        System.out.println(grid[i[0]][i[1]].getPosition());
        if (grid[i[0]][i[1]].getIsExit()) {
            System.out.println("Path been found!");
            arrayDeque.remove(i);
        } else if (grid[i[0]][i[1]].getType() == 1) {
            System.out.println("Path been blocked!");
            arrayDeque.remove(i);
        } else if (grid[i[0]][i[1]].getIsVisited()) {
            arrayDeque.remove(i);
        }
```

none of these conditions are true in the beginning so we can skip them.

```
else
{
    grid[i[0]][i[1]].setIsVisited(true);
```

I set the node with position = visited, so I don't get to check it out again.

Out of these conditions only (1) and (3) are true, so we add 2 int[] arrays to the deque:

```
if (i[0] < gridLength - 1) {
    int[] c = i;
    c[0]++;
    arrayDeque.add(c);
}
if (i[0] > 0) {
    int[] d = i;
    d[0]--;
    arrayDeque.add(d);
}
if (i[1] < gridLength - 1) {
    int[] e = i;
    e[1]++;
    arrayDeque.add(e);
}
if (i[1] > 0) {
    int[] f = i;
    f[1]--;
    arrayDeque.add(f);
}
```

Lastly, we remove the visited node:

```
arrayDeque.remove(i);
```

What I get in the output is:

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

So where is the code off?

Comment: Maybe removing some of the large whitespaces from your code could help in reading it more easily (its kinda annoying ;))

Comment: So what does this have to do with `[artificial-intelligence]` ?

Comment: Because AIs use blind search algorithms.

Comment: 1) No they don't.  Or at least ... not if they are "intelligent".  2) Even if they did, that doesn't  make this question relevant to AI's.

Comment: But either way, I'm not going to try to read your code in its current (hard to read) state.

Comment: @GrindingForReputation there are not more than 2-3 empty lines in my code imo.

Comment: @StephenC funny because the class im taking in my university is called "Artificial Intelligence" and we are being taught these in the first 3 chapters.So I guess universities teach the wrong things , hmm ?

Comment: @RootGroves if you're using eclipse use ctrl+shift+f to format your code I'm not joking when i say its annoying to read.

Comment: You want every line to have code?

Comment: Not exactly, what I am asking you to do is to change the following in your code -> Remove 2-3 empty lines, one works fine. Secondly fix the indentation (1 indent = 4 spaces). Remove unnecessary empty lines, you dont need an empty line after     `int[] e = i;` and `e[1]++;`

Comment: You have already said :" Go and ask your AI course lecturer if they think that a question about debugging a BFS code is about artificial intelligence" and "1) No they don't. Or at least ... not if they are "intelligent". 2) Even if they did, that doesn't make this question relevant to AI's."

Comment: No.  I'm trying to get you to >fix< your question.  So is Grinding.  And all you are doing is wasting everyone's time by arguing about stupid things and calling people names an.

Comment: Ok I will remove off the tag artificial intelligence, ok?

Comment: [PLONK](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26890646)

Comment: @RootGroves Stephen is not wrong, this is a simple program that is not related with artificial intelligence at all (or at least not directly), you think this program is directly related to something as complicated as ai? Maybe it is but could be a really really small portion of what ai needs to make decisions.

Comment: I would post an edit but I have too many pending edits currently so I cannot format the code myself.

Comment: Its been done!No need of worries.

Comment: Please provide enough code for us to be able to copy & run it. As it stands now, your question lists several pieces of code, with references to variables that are not known. Although a link to your previous question is informative, it does not mean you don't have to provide the code necessary to understand the current question. Each question should be self-contained, and we should be able to run the code without having to invent stuff to make it compile. And when we run it, it should produce the problem.

Comment: Please check out [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/) as well as the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) links. They won't solve the actual problem but can give you steps that help you either solve it, or help you to focus the issue more which can help you improve this question. Otherwise, you're learning how to dump work for others to solve and not how solve code problems yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are not dealing correctly with the positions. This code mutates `i`:

```
    int[] c = i;
    c[0]++;
```

You seem to think that `c` is a *copy* of the *array*, but it is not. It merely references the array that `i` references, and so when you do `c[0]++`, that *single* array now has that incremented value. The next time you apply this kind of code (in one of the next `if` blocks), you'll not start with the original position, but with the already mutated `i`, and so your "steps" are going astray.

Honestly, I had already indicated in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77541631/5459839) that working with the idea of array-type positions leads to less elegant code, and now we see how easy it is to introduce bugs with it.

If you work with such arrays, you'll have to really construct new arrays and copy the contents of the original array.

Here is the correction of that part of your code:

```
        if (i[0] < gridLength - 1) {
            arrayDeque.add(new int[] {i[0]+1, i[1]});
        }
        if (i[0] > 0) {
            arrayDeque.add(new int[] {i[0]-1, i[1]});
        }
        if (i[1] < gridLength - 1) {
            arrayDeque.add(new int[] {i[0], i[1]+1});
        }
        if (i[1] > 0) {
            arrayDeque.add(new int[] {i[0], i[1]-1});
        }
```

Comment: I have already solved it!You need to say that for e.g path to the right i[0]++; int[] c = i.clone();

Comment: There are several ways to do it. With `clone` you still need a variable assignment. What I proposed here is to have an expression that generates the array as argument. But in my opinion, all this is less readable code than using separate integers. And if you do `i[0]++`, you need still a `i[0]--` to restore `i` to its original value as otherwise the next `if` blocks will again go astray. If you want to use `clone`, then do `int[] c = i.clone(); c[0]++;`. That way you don't mutate `i`, which is what you need.